# How do i convert response and request headers to arraybuffers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do i convert response and request headers to arraybuffers and vice versa?

Sorry, can't seem to find the answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const headers = { method: 'GET', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' };

// to ArrayBuffer
Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  headers[key] = new TextEncoder().encode(val).buffer;
});

// from ArrayBuffer
Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  headers[key] = new TextDecoder().decode(val);
});
```

Comment: actually i'm asking more like if it's possible to convert headers => arrayBuffers without looping and foreach. just straight of headers => arrayBuffers and vice versa. is this possible?

Comment: You want to encode the `JSON` `String` `{ "method": GET", "Content-Type": "text/plain" }` as an `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: No. request.Header => arrayBuffers . is this possible? no need to jsonify etc so I can just convert ArrayBuffers back to RequestHeader. this is mainly to speed up storage retrieval purposes. if to break down and loop for header items, it's kind of redundant. basically once header => arrayBuffers, i can just store the ArrayBuffers and then retrieval and make into requestheader immediately without reconstructing it by looping the items.

Comment: `new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(your_header_object)).buffer`.  Yes, you have to use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: If you had a faster encoding than `JSON`, you would not be asking how to encode headers as an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: oic, u are right.  i hate json.stringify, the problem is the storage medium process arraybuffer faster and more efficiently that's all. to do a double conversion is kind of redundant in this. do u think stringify is faster than the foreach loop answer you have given?

Comment: A storage medium like a harddrive doesn't know the difference between an `ArrayBuffer` or a `JSON` string because they are both viewed as mere sequences of binary digits, so what you are saying cannot be the case.  Feel free to post a new question asking how to speed up storage and retrieval of your `JSON`.  But be sure to explain exactly how you're going about it right now, and share your actual code.

Comment: nope, using special cloud storage, which can tell the difference.

Comment: The question you posed has been answered; if you are confused regarding what problem you are actually trying to solve, open a new question that includes all relevant code you've tried.